# Recognising an image variable in Ruby on Rails HTML to run jquery Image Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the Simple jQuery Image Magnifier & Enlargement Plugin - imagezoom with ruby on rails and cannot find a way to reference an image variable within the show.html.erb file.

The code in my html I am trying to make work is:

```
<script src="imagezoom.js"></script>
<style>
.thumb-image { width: 500px; }
.thumb-image > img { width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>

  <div class="row">
    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="<%= image_tag @product.img_url %>" data-imagezoom="true"> </div>
```

The image_tag @product.img_url references an image in the assets folder, however the standard jquery code is looking for an image in the conventional way e.g.

`<img src="**/assets/image1.jpg**" data-imagezoom="true">`

Is there a way I can reference the image variable in the HTML so the zoom function will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<img src="<%= image_tag @product.img_url %>" data-imagezoom="true">
```

Just do:

```
<%= image_tag @product.img_url, :data => { :imagezoom => "true" } %>
```

Checkout the documentation of [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) method for more information.

Comment: Just genius! That worked perfectly! I will checkout image_tag documentation as suggested. Your help is greatly appreciated.